# My do-while loop doesn't seem to be executing my if statement

Tags: java

I'm new to java, so sorry if my programming skills are poor. My program needs to use a queue to simulate an I/O buffer. It continually accepts lines of user input. If the user inserts an O(Oh) it returns the first line entered. If an X is entered it needs to end.

This is my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String check = input.nextLine();

do {

  queue.add(check);

  if(check.equals("O")) {

     if(queue.peek() != null){
        String remove = queue.remove();
        System.out.println("Data: " + remove);
        }

     else if(queue.peek() == null) {
        System.out.println("Buffer empty");         
        }
  } 

 } while(!"X".equals(check)) ;
```

The expected input-output is:

```
line1
line2
O
Data: line1
line3
line4
O
Data: line2
O
Data: line3
line5
O
Data: line4
O
Data: line5
O
Buffer empty 
X
```

My program doesn't seem to execute my if statement, as it never stops asking for input and doesn't exit once and X is given by the user.

I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: `it never stops asking for input` - Impossible. The input part is **before** the loop, it will ask for input just once, and you'll have an infinite loop if the input is different from `X`. Perhaps you posted an old version of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input.nextLine()` is outside of the loop so it's only called once, when adding input to your queue is called on every loop iteration, that's why it's happening. Change it this way:

```java
String check;
do {
  check = input.nextLine();
  queue.add(check);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you need to read the input again at the end, after the if condition, you need to add the line:

```
check = input.nextLine();
```

this way you read the next inputline, otherwise check will always be the same thing which is the first thing entered.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
String check = input.nextLine();
```

is called only once whereas it should be called again at the end of the loop. So it is not updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation that makes a lot of sense. How would I call is again? Just simple put:     String check = input.nextLine();  at the end

Comment: Nah, only check = input.nextLine(); because you don't declare another string.